# Waiting on job "x" to finish in pipeline "1" before running job "x" in pipeline "2" (Azure DevOps)

Tags: azure-devops, sonarqube, azure-pipelines

We're using SonarQube for tests, and there's one token it uses, as long as one pipeline is running, it goes fine, but if I run different pipelines (all of them have E2E tests as final jobs), they all fail, because they keep calling a token that expires as soon as its used by one pipeline (job). Would it be possible to have -all- pipelines pause at job "x" if they detect some pipeline running job "x" already? The jobs have same names across all pipelines. Yes, I know this is solved by just running one pipeline at a time, but that's not what my devs wanna do.

Comment: When a job targets an environment, you can control how many jobs run against that environment at the same time. It's a bit of a hack, but it would work. Constraining this job to a single agent of which there is only 1 would work as well.

Comment: Hi @sneedster, is the answer below to set demands for your agent job to run on a specific self-hosted agent helps you? If it helps, just a remind of [accept an answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to make jobs run one by one is set demands for your agent job to run on a specific self-hosted agent. Just as below, set a user-defined capabilities for the self-hosted agent and then require run on the agent by setting demands in agent job.

[image]

[image]

In this way, agent jobs will only run on this agent. Build will run one by one until the previous one complete.

Besides, you could control if a job should run by defining approvals and checks. By using [Invoke REST API check](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/approvals?view=azure-devops&tabs=check-pass#invoke-rest-api) to make a call to a REST API such as [Gets a list of builds](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/builds/list?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0), and define the success criteria as build count is zero, then, next build starts.